# Choose object attribute based on type of passed object

Tags: typescript

In the code below:

```
enum FirstSourceTopicAliases {
    Topic = 'topic',
    TopicText = 'topic_text',
    TopicLink = 'topic_link',
}
enum SecondSourceTopicAliases {
    Topic = 'title',
    TopicText = 'body',
    TopicLink = 'link',
}
interface FirstSourceTopic {
    [FirstSourceTopicAliases.Topic]: string,
    [FirstSourceTopicAliases.TopicText]: string,
    [FirstSourceTopicAliases.TopicLink]: string,
}
interface SecondSourceTopic {
    [SecondSourceTopicAliases.Topic]: string,
    [SecondSourceTopicAliases.TopicText]: string,
    [SecondSourceTopicAliases.TopicLink]: string,
}

type Topic = FirstSourceTopic | SecondSourceTopic

const parseTopic = (topic: Topic) => {
    const parsedTopic = {
        topic: 'parsed' + topic.topic // or topic.title
        topicText: 'parsed' + topic.topic_text // or topic.body
        topicLink: 'parsed' + topic.topic_link, // or topic.link
    }

    return parsedTopic
}

const firstSourceTopic: FirstSourceTopic = {
    topic: 'some topic',
    topic_text: 'some topic text',
    topic_link: 'some topic link',
}
const secondSourceTopic: SecondSourceTopic = {
    title: 'some topic',
    body: 'some topic text',
    link: 'some topic link',
}

const parsedTopic = parseTopic(firstSourceTopic)
console.log(parsedTopic)
```

Is it possible to make `parseRow` function generic enough so that it knows what key to extract from `topic` object that is passed to it? Currently the compiler will complain if I choose one of the attributes because the attribute is not present on the other type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a disciminator field property to disambiguate between your types (currently you have no intersection), e.g.

```
enum FirstSourceTopicAliases {
    Topic = 'topic',
    TopicText = 'topic_text',
    TopicLink = 'topic_link',
}
enum SecondSourceTopicAliases {
    Topic = 'title',
    TopicText = 'body',
    TopicLink = 'link',
}
interface FirstSourceTopic {
    kind:'first',
    [FirstSourceTopicAliases.Topic]: string,
    [FirstSourceTopicAliases.TopicText]: string,
    [FirstSourceTopicAliases.TopicLink]: string,
}
interface SecondSourceTopic {
       kind:'second',
    [SecondSourceTopicAliases.Topic]: string,
    [SecondSourceTopicAliases.TopicText]: string,
    [SecondSourceTopicAliases.TopicLink]: string,
}

type Topic = FirstSourceTopic | SecondSourceTopic

const parseTopic = <T extends FirstSourceTopic | SecondSourceTopic>(topic: T) => {
    if (topic.kind==='first') {
        return {
        topic: 'parsed' + topic.topic ,
        topicText: 'parsed' + topic.topic_text, 
        topicLink: 'parsed' + topic.topic_link, 
    }}
    return {
        topic: 'parsed' + topic.title ,
        topicText: 'parsed' + topic.body, 
        topicLink: 'parsed' + topic.link, 
    }
}

const firstSourceTopic: FirstSourceTopic = {
    kind:'first',
    topic: 'some topic',
    topic_text: 'some topic text',
    topic_link: 'some topic link',
}
const secondSourceTopic: SecondSourceTopic = {
    kind:'second',
    title: 'some topic',
    body: 'some topic text',
    link: 'some topic link',
}

const parsedTopic = parseTopic(firstSourceTopic)
console.log(parsedTopic)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglgJwM4BcDKB7MCDGwAqGADnDgIIA2cAhksElAN4BQUbUhJOUAvFAOQpipfgBpW7TqXzAAHil4ChXAPoo5KMRLZScAGTggA1osHCcKqsa0BfZqEhQ0wHBhAATTNjy7KNOgws7BzmpihwKBTAWsG6MvKmAEYY7gCeMZLmBsamVka2zIbqCABm1HiwiKheuAShQexGhu4AXPwlVZriwQDa8MjoWLW%20VLT0AHS6ALotUKgIhgDm3ex9nTU%205n5jSJPm8SgzcygLIMvaUGsDG3Vc2wF7XNlGR-NL4nZFwKXlwE4ubk8Q02XCYF0azTadFcHgybB6zhhQO8t1I9wm01mbzOK3hiMBNxG-gx%20w0rxO7wuCIBHkJW1GD10z3Jp3OdmYKFSRD%20ukU-WqwNR3AAPv8kXSuMxmDDUFAiNRkELFAAefBQDSgdwMfmDFG80X42mC3QAPgAFMpSLN8ABKXgmsHBOAlKAW8zjJoeHje9qdfh2hrBNgIYAobAgR1BtiWnCzfjyxXufhQADUUBj4xjUFEAHoc1AMAh0%207wpFgOD2DGDnGE3Qk6ni1xM%20Y1BpRFA8wWixnkmkK9GsoYjDWFXXk2mMzHLEP253C43SOM8hcbHZgiGwwgI4GgzGR4nxwucJmIlFs3PuyXT%20WowOuNWBLXgPWJ%207e6lZ-n5z2Uql%200fnn3McGwzPJPy7I8lyHFdmHZGUFA6a5jXMWYdQlUhFB3T1Wl9AY4SPOMkAwCA-hjfCp3UeRCOI0jQkoroLinPJqJIo8oDyAp4LmGlkWGFCxQJZDQT4LDIX4aFAXI68WNorh8PfGS2Po-DmIEIjWKzDiPilLin3cXk%20CfXQzUQgU9XMG1pTcIioiXDBFjNPTdBtIA)